# Ordering by a Column that's not in the Group By or Enapsulated in an Aggregate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem getting this JPA query to work on MS SQL Server 2008.

The background is as follows: Users create jobs for clients, of which there are many. I am displaying a list of his most recently used clients to the user to make the selection easier.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Client c 
    JOIN c.jobs j 
    WHERE j.user = ?1 
    ORDER BY j.created DESC
```

The query works just fine - using MySQL. MS SQL Server (2008) complains that I cannot sort by `j.created` because it is not part of the select list. This is the error message:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the
>   select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified.

I can't seem to find an elegant workaround for this limitation. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Where's your JOINing clause? This will give you every row of c linked to every row of j matching your parameter.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight: No, this is JPA query language, not SQL. "JOIN c.jobs" is the full join clause.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Can't say I like the illusory similarity to SQL.

Comment: Yea... How about another layer of abstraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are selecting a distinct c from many, Sql server won't know which j.created to order by. You can group by c and then use an aggregate to order by the min or max j.created. Something like...

```
SELECT c.col1, c.col2 
FROM Client c 
JOIN c.jobs j 
WHERE j.user = ?1 
Group by c.col1, c.col2
ORDER BY MIN(j.created) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a limitation of SQL. The problem is that the sort doesn't make sense in terms of your query. The Distinct operator is going to aggregate multiple values of C each of which might have a different create date. So in this situation how would SQL sort it?

```
C    Create  
1    1/1/2009  
2    3/1/2008  
1    12/2/2009  
9    4/1/2009
```

Comment: I should have seen the problem. I wonder what MySQL does... probably applies the ORDER BY first, and then the DISTINCT, which would explain why it worked. Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

May be this question is a bit old but I have found a easier workaround.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Client c 
    JOIN fetch c.jobs j 
    WHERE j.user = ?1 
    ORDER BY j.created DESC
```

Adding the `fetch` keyword to the join with tell JPA to include fields in the join in the select statement so `mssql` would no longer complaint about it.

Answer (score 0):

Duckworth's answer pretty much solved the problem, so this is only for reference.

This was my first attempt after reading duck's and John's answers:

```
SELECT c FROM Client c JOIN c.jobs j 
    WHERE j.user = ?1 
    GROUP BY c 
    ORDER BY MIN(j.created) DESC
```

But selecting the full entites directly does not play with the GROUP BY clause, and results in a `SQLGrammarException`.

Instead, I now get only the IDs using this query:

```
SELECT c.id FROM Client c JOIN c.jobs j 
    WHERE j.user = ?1 
    GROUP BY c.id 
    ORDER BY MIN(j.created) DESC
```

Then I only have to fetch the entities using the IDs.

Thanks, everybody!